# Ruby on Rails - chaining preprocessor engines

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, erb, preprocessor

Let's say I have **custom.js.coffee** file which gets run through the CoffeeScript processor, and file **custom.js.erb.coffee** which gets run through both CoffeeScript and ERb processors.

What would be the benefit of chaining preprocessor engines as such?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What would be the benefit of chaining preprocessor engines as such?

ERB is a simple templating system for Ruby, embedding code in any plain-text document (or any other such `css`, `js`, `yml`, `html` and so on), that means you are able to use the ruby code in those files. First step is erb preprocessing (execute ruby code and paste the result), then coffee converted to the js code and send to the web page. The benefit is generated file which can depend on the ruby logic, and passing the data from ruby to the js.

<sup>BTW you can omit the `erb` extension and you will still be able to use `erb` code in those files.</sup>